# Can IFTTT be used to refresh a webpage and report back if it's changed?

Tags: if-this-then-that

Is there a way to refresh specific tabs periodically on the browser and report back any changes with a recipe in IFTTT? How can a specific browser window be targeted when more than one is open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not something IFTTT can do. IFTTT acts as a "bridge" between two different APIs. It also needs to work from the IFTTT servers, and they don't have any access to your local...anything.

You'll need to find a different way to do what you're looking to do.

There are services out there that purport to turn changes to a web page into RSS. You could then use one of them with IFTTT to monitor a page for changes, but it wouldn't be in real-time, and probably won't work for all pages. From what I recall, IFTTT recipes don't run more frequently than every 15 minutes, not to mention whatever frequency is set by the service you're using to convert changes into RSS.

Comment: Does IFTTT have no way to run code continuously eg track a page continuously?

Answer (score 0):

You could use followthatpage.com which will send you an email, then (probably) use a customised gmail (etc) trigger for IFTTT.... though the 'report' is already followthatpage so that may be all you need!

Comment: Link down......

Comment: for a few days, on a 4 year old answer. Comment not needed.